# Apostrophe in Create Account causes error

Tags: docusignapi

When I create a new account through the REST API using the following JSON, which contains an apostrophe in the accountName

```
{
   "accountName":"St. Matthew's Hospital",
   "planInformation":{
      "currencyCode":"USD",
      "planId":"55555555-5555-5555-55555-5555555555"
   },
   "distributorCode":"Acme Partner",
   "distributorPassword":"Acme-N0h4ck1ng",
   "initialUser":{
      "email":"smh@gmail.com",
      "enableConnectForUser":"false",
      "password":"asdf123",
      "userName":"St. Matthew's Hospital"
   }
}
```

...the account is created, but when I log in to the DocuSign console as the new user and navigate to preferences, I get this error in the:

Invalid Form Value
Characters not allowed.
The &# combination and < > can be an indication of a malicious attack. We block these characters in input fields. Please remove them and try again.
For help: support@docusign.com

Is it possible to create an account with an apostrophe in the name?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try to escape the quote character?  I believe something like this should work:

```
"accountName":"St. Matthew\'s Hospital",
```

Comment: Seems like escaping the single quote as Ergin shows in this answer should do the trick.  I have employed this technique before when updating "lastName" in a user's profile (example JSON: "lastName":"O\'Leary").

Comment: I tried escaping it, but I get the same result.  It's not a problem creating the account - it creates just fine.  The problem is in the DocuSign console web UI while logged in as the created account.

Comment: This looks to me like a bug in the DocuSign web console.  Ergin, can you create a bug to get it fixed?  This is a problem for us as we do have some customers with apostrophes in their names and it looks unprofessional to leave the apostrophe out which would appear like that in emails, signing views, etc.